# XPath - retrieving the parent of a descendant that meets a criteria

Tags: xpath

Given the following structure:

A. body node as root
B. body contains only span nodes, call them top-level spans
C. top-level spans contains combinations of (1) text nodes (2) spans with class, call them lower level spans
D. lower level spans contains text nodes only

We need to retrieve each top-level span which have one or more lower level spans with classes "a" or "b".

Our best shot yet:

```
//span//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' qri ') or contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' ktiv ')]
```

but it gives the lower level spans.

Demonstration:

```js
x = new XPathEvaluator();
var it = x.evaluate("//span//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a ') or contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' b ')]", document.body.cloneNode(true));
var results = [];
for (var current = it.iterateNext(); current; current = it.iterateNext()) {
  results.push(current.id);
}
console.log(results);
```

```html
<span id="top1">In a<span id="a1" class="a">ultrices felis</span><span id="b1" class="b">sollicitudin felis</span></span>
<span id="top2">congue velit<span id="a2" class="a">Sed porttitor</span>Phasellus posuere</span>
<span id="top3">purus. Etiam<span id="b2" class="b">tellus, ultrices</span>Morbi interdum</span>
<span id="top4">leo malesuada tristique</span>
```

Desired output is:

```
[
    "top1",
    "top2",
    "top3"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following XPath

```
//span[.//span[@class = 'a' or @class='b']]
```

It selects all `span`s which have one or more `span` children of `class` `a` or `b`.

If you need it even more specific, add a `parent::` axis

```
//span[parent::body and .//span[@class = 'a' or @class='b']]
```

Another possibility is an absolute path:

```
/body/span[.//span[@class = 'a' or @class='b']]
```